# HTML+JQUERY <tags> moved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working with a code developed by some other. 
It is a web developed with PHP, HTML and JQUERY (wordpress with woocomerce).

I need to insert some tabs in a  that it's already done.
The problem is that (I think) the  are moved.
When I click on "View source code" I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function() {
      jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   });

</script>
<table class="variations-table" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
         <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Americana">Americana</a></li>
         <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Chaleco">Chaleco</a></li>
         <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Pantalones">Pantalones</a></li>
      </ul>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <div id="Americana">
               <tr>
                  <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
                     <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
                     <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Tejido</p>
                     <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido" class="shopping">
                     <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">Leo Black</p>
                     <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </div>
            <div id="Chaleco">
               <tr>
                  <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
                     <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
                     <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Chaleco bolsillo</p>
                     <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido" class="shopping">
                     <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">1 bolsillo</p>
                     <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </div>
            <div id="Pantalones">
               <tr>
                  <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
                     <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
                     <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Chaleco bolsillo</p>
                     <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido"             
                        class="shopping">
                     <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">1 bolsillo</p>
                     <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </div>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

But, when I click on "Inspect Element" (Chrome of Firefox) the tag div are moved out of the tag table:

```
    '<div id="tabs">
       <ul>
          <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Americana">Americana</a></li>
          <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Chaleco">Chaleco</a></li>
          <li style="background:none;"><a href="#Pantalones">Pantalones</a></li>
       </ul>
       <table>
       <tbody>
          <div id="Americana">
          </div>
    </div>
    <table class="variations-table" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
    <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
    <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Tejido</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido" class="shopping">
    <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">Leo Black</p>
    <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="Chaleco">
    <tr>
    <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
    <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
    <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Chaleco bolsillo</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido" class="shopping">
    <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">1 bolsillo</p>
    <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <div id="Pantalones">
    <tr>
    <td class="label cabecera tejido" >
    <label for="tejido" style="display:none"></label>
    <p class="tejido-leo-black etiqueta etiqueta-1" >Chaleco bolsillo</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="Leo Black" id="tejido" name="attribute_tejido" class="shopping">
    <p class="seleccion select-1 select-tejido">1 bolsillo</p>
    <div class="personalizar desplegable-1 abrir-1" >Personalizar</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>'
```

I don't know if it is normal or not.

Any help appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The HTML code is invalid. One cannot place a `div` tag inside a `tbody`. It must at least be positioned inside a `td`. Chrome / Firefox try to fix this, that's why you see different ordering in the inspector.

Comment: @GhostGambler
thanks. Now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
<tbody>
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
```

You can't just throw a `div` inside a `<tbody>`, create a cell (preferably after a row), then add.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
         ...
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```